# Problem with MySQL timezone

Tags: freebsd, mysql, synchronization, timezone, jails

I have installed MySQL,version 5.6.16.My OS is FreeBSD,version is 9.3.MySQL installed on jail.When I check date I see Thu Nov 17 15:22:14 AMT 2016,I see this output also on the system.In MySQL,when I checked SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; I see that global and session time zones set to SYSTEM.But when I check SELECT NOW(); I see `2016-11-17` `11:23:44.I` know that I can set in MySQL manually`

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+4:00';
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Yerevan';
SET @@global.time_zone = '+04:00';
```

But I want to synchronize with system time.I know also that I can put in `my.cnf` `default_time_zone=Asia/Yerevan` or `default-time-zone=+04:00`.But this is production server and I can't restart the server.Please help us to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258274/mysql-query-for-current-gmt-time